# fixed header displayed over content, but there is a gap at the top,

Tags: html, header, z-index, css-position

so I have fixed and centered the header, and the z-index achieves it  being over the top of content that scrolls, however there is a small gap at the top.

I tried using overflow:auto but it did not work as I had hoped.

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<header class="site-header delay fadeInDown animated">
    <a class="header-link fadeInDown animated" href="/">
    <h1>BryanBell</h1>
    </a>
</header>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
font-family:"CubanoRegular";
font-size:72px;
letter-spacing:12pt;
line-height:120%;
text-align:center;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#ccc));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
margin:50px;
padding:25px;

}

header {
position:fixed;
text-align:center;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%; 
height:150px;
z-index:999;
background-image: url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/cartographer.png')
```

Comment: What is the problem? Here is the fiddle of your code, http://jsfiddle.net/d57BN/, I don't see any gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
html{
    margin-top:0;
    padding-top:0;
}
body{
    margin-top:0;
    padding-top:0;
}
```

Comment: yea, no problem.  BTW you can also do what the other guy did, combine both the html and body elements in one, the way he did.  you don't need width: 10% and height:100% though unless you really screw something up.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the page has a small amount of `margin`.

Therefore, for things like this, we need to reset the `margin` and `padding` to `0`.

I also usually set the `width` and `height` to `100%` as well, like this:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

The reason that [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) displays it fine is that it has already reset the `margin` and `padding`.

Answer (score 0):

Add inside the header:

```
<header style="top: 0px">
```