# Fixed header in Android webapp

Tags: android, html, cordova, web-applications

I am creating an HTML5 app in Android using phonegap. I am testing my code on an Android device version 2.3.6. I am not using Jquery mobile or any other framework. Everything is just HTML, CSS and jQuery. I want to have a fixed header. This is how my CSS looks at the moment:

```
.header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:2em;
    line-height:2;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:x-large;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#f6f6f6;
    background-color:#00539e;
    z-index:2000;
    padding-left:2em;
    padding-right:2em;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

Things work fine until I click on an input field and open the soft keyboard. Moment the keyboard opens there appears on top and to the left of header a 1pixel gap. Have a look at the screenshot: [image: screenshot]
.

I have tried various suggestions in SO (e.g. [fixed header displayed over content, but there is a gap at the top,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463059/fixed-header-displayed-over-content-but-there-is-a-gap-at-the-top)) but none has worked for me so far. Any more ideas?

The relevant parts of the code are here:(http://jsfiddle.net/tZwyW/3/). The problem does not show up on desktop browsers.

Comment: can you put a bit more code like html,xml(layout)

Comment: @boburShox, I have created a jsfiddle for the code.